# Economics.SE traffic update

Tags: discussion

The last thirteen weeks (Mon Feb 1 to Sun May 1, 2016) appear relatively stationary (with daily seasonality of course):

[image]

So sample daily averages are meaningful:

[image]

In the last week of April 2015, daily traffic was between $[300, 450]$...

...and we have come a long way from last summer:

[image]

Comment: Comparing April averages to summer averages seems strange. I seem to recall there is a huge drop during the summer months.

Comment: @denesp. Generally, it does not take into account quarterly seasonality indeed. But in our case, traffic increased up to May 2015, then stayed ~stable for the duration of the summer, and then visibly increased as Autumn 2015 set in. So summer 2015 was like ~Spring 2015, and since I  had the graph ready I included it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update. As a 'softer' metric, here is the current [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics) data:

[image]

We indeed seem to be firmly rooted into the excellent category for traffic-related stats. I guess we now have a fairly health user-base and good search engine visibility.

I am not too worried about % answered and number of answers per question because my impression is that we have quite a lot of low-quality questions on the site and that the good questions tend to get answered fairly promptly.

The thing that worries me a little more is the number of questions per day. This seems to be slowly declining, and is obviously important for the long-run vitality of the site.

Comment: Re: Questions. See additional data in an answer I posted. Re: Questions answered. I also don't worry as long as it stays above 70% (the 90% benchmark is for simpler and less diverse fields of knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

Following on @Ubiquitous answer, questions per week in the first four months of 2016 seem to also be stable. There was an apparent upward trend in mid-March, but it didn't last.

[image]

A different and more general worry could be "What? We have stabilized? So this is *it*?"

I can understand this "grow or perish" mentality, but in real life growth many times happens in "waves", and after each wave there is a period of stability.

However adventurous it may be to use data from the first months in beta, it may be the case that we will have to "wait it out" (meaning, energetically care-taking for the site in the meantime), until September 2016.